# What's the title of a short sci fi story about how the universe doesn't want the past to change?

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, time-travel

I read the short story years ago about a con man who keeps trying to use time travel to get an inheritance. After all his scheming the universe uses a small meteor to kill the man in order to stop his meddling.

What's the name of that story?

Answer (score 17):

["Try and Change the Past"](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?55666) by [Fritz Leiber](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fritz_Leiber) (first published in [*Astounding Science Fiction*, March 1958](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?57579+c), available at the [Internet Archive](https://archive.org/stream/Astounding_v61n01_1958-03_EXciter-LennyS#page/n91/mode/2up)), a story in Leiber's [*Change War*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pe.cgi?4228) series:

> If a statistician is looking for an example of a highly improbable event, he can hardly pick a more vivid one than the chance of a man being hit by a meteorite. And, if he adds the condition that the meteorite hit him between the eyes so as to counterfeit the wound made by a 32-caliber bullet, the improbability becomes astronomical cubed. So how's a person going to outmaneuver a universe that finds it easier to drill a man through the head that way than postpone the day of his death?

You may have read it in one of [these](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/titlecovers.cgi?55666).